# convert (nx2) array of floats into (nx1) array of 2-tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, casting, user-defined-types

I have a NumPy float array

```py
x = np.array([
    [0.0, 1.0],
    [2.0, 3.0],
    [4.0, 5.0]
    ],
    dtype=np.float32
    )
```

and need to convert it into a NumPy array with a tuple dtype,

```py
y = np.array([
    (0.0, 1.0),
    (2.0, 3.0),
    (4.0, 5.0)
    ],
    dtype=np.dtype((np.float32, 2))
    )
```

NumPy [`view`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html)s unfortunately don't work here:

```py
y = x.view(dtype=np.dtype((np.float32, 2)))
```

```
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

Is there a chance to get this done without iterating through `x` and copying over every single entry?

Comment: Take a look at the `view` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close:

```
In [122]: dt=np.dtype([('x',float,(2,))])

In [123]: y=np.zeros(x.shape[0],dtype=dt)

In [124]: y
Out[124]: 
array([([0.0, 0.0],), ([0.0, 0.0],), ([0.0, 0.0],)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8', (2,))])

In [125]: y['x']=x

In [126]: y
Out[126]: 
array([([0.0, 1.0],), ([2.0, 3.0],), ([4.0, 5.0],)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8', (2,))])

In [127]: y['x']
Out[127]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.]])
```

`y` has one compound field.  That field has 2 elements.

Alternatively you could define 2 fields:

```
In [134]: dt=np.dtype('f,f')
In [135]: x.view(dt)
Out[135]: 
array([[(0.0, 1.0)],
       [(2.0, 3.0)],
       [(4.0, 5.0)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

But that is shape (3,1); so reshape:

```
In [137]: x.view(dt).reshape(3)
Out[137]: 
array([(0.0, 1.0), (2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

Apart from the dtype that displays the same as your `y`.